# Sull'uso del vocabolo "nonsocosa"

Tags: word-usage

Nel racconto *Il niente e il poco* di Italo Calvino ho letto questa lunghissima frase:

> A noi sembrava già una gran cosa, e lo era certamente, perché solo se cominci a esistere virtualmente, a fluttuare in un campo di probabilità, a prendere in prestito e a restituire cariche d'energia ancora tutte ipotetiche, ti può capitare una volta o l'altra
>   d'esistere di fatto, cioè di curvare intorno a te un lembo di spazio-tempo anche minimo: come successe a una quantità sempre crescente di **nonsocosa** -- chiamiamoli
>   neutrini perché è un bel nome, ma allora i neutrini nessuno se li era mai sognati -- ondeggianti uno addosso all'altro in una zuppa rovente d'un calore infinito, spessa
>   come una colla di densità infinita, che si gonfiava in un tempo così infinitamente
>   breve che non aveva niente a che fare col tempo -- e difatti il tempo non aveva avuto
>   ancora tempo di dimostrare cosa sarebbe stato -- e gonfiandosi produceva spazio dove
>   lo spazio non s'era mai saputo cosa fosse.

Ho trovato molto curiosa e divertente la parola "nonsocosa" e mi sono chiesta fino a che punto potessi usarla anch'io. Ho visto che non si trova nei dizionari, perlomeno in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Su [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonsocosa&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnonsocosa%3B%2Cc0) però si trova qualche occorrenza. La mia domanda è sull'uso che se ne fa nell'italiano attuale: si usa ancora molto raramente o si usa sempre di più? Il suo uso è limitato a contesti molto informali?

Comment: Di solito si usano le espressioni *non so cosa* o *non so che* con gli spazi

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ma queste espressioni si usano anche come un sostantivo? Cioè, posso scrivere "una quantità di non so cosa" o "una quantità di non so che"?

Comment: Senza dubbio, anche se i tuoi usi mi suonano poco idiomatici. Ma vedi ad esempio *un certo non so che* https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+certo+non+so+che&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20certo%20non%20so%20che%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Vedi anche https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+non+so+cosa%2Cun+non+so+che&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20non%20so%20cosa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20non%20so%20che%3B%2Cc0 (*un non so che* è invisibile perché molto meno usato, ma non zero)

Comment: In inglese sarebbe *whatsit*. Si potrebbe dire *cosi* invece di *nonsocosa* (un *coso* è un oggetto o un concetto senza nome o il cui nome ci siamo dimenticati).

Comment: @DenisNardin: Hai ragione, [nel Treccani appare "non so che"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/non-so-che/). In altri dizionari, come spiegato nella risposta di egreg, si trova "nonsoché".

Comment: @Charo, se hai un poco più familiarità con l'inglese, alcune delle espressioni che usano spesso per rendere la stessa idea è *thingamajig* o *whatchamacallit* e varianti. Non è comunissimo ma se lo usi nessuno si scandalizzerebbe e tutti sono in grado di capire cosa intendi

Answer (score 2):

In italiano parlato è abbastanza frequente riferirsi a un *coso* se di quell'oggetto o concetto non ci ricordiamo il nome. Oppure non ce l'ha proprio.

Qui Calvino vuole dire che forse un nome c'è, ma che non lo conosce. Si inventa un “segnaposto” facendo della locuzione *non so cosa* un nome unico.

La questione se si adopera in italiano corrente è mal posta. È una “parola temporanea”, si potrebbe dire.

Più frequente, almeno in tempi passati, *nonsoché* per indicare qualcosa di sfuggente, indeterminato.

In inglese si può trovare un corrispondente *whatsit*.

Comment: Non capisco bene perché dici che "la questione se si adopera in italiano corrente è mal posta". Vuoi dire che il vocabolo non si usa perché è un'invenzione di Calvino (e le occorrenze su Google Books sono forse refusi)?

Comment: @Charo Non è un'invenzione di Calvino, né un refuso. Usalo se ti va e se ne hai un buon motivo: per questo la questione è mal posta.

Comment: Ma la mia domanda non era tanto se si può usare o meno questo vocabolo, ma sulla frequenza e i contesti di uso se veramente si sta usando nell'italiano di oggi.

Comment: @Charo Non riesco a farmi capire, ci riprovo: non ha senso domandarsi se sia una parola di uso frequente o raro. Nel contesto particolare rende l'idea; se non ne abusi va benissimo.

Comment: @Charo Per rispondere esplicitamente alla tua domanda: sì, nella mia esperienza è d'uso comune

Comment: @egreg: Condivido nel complesso il tuo ragionamento, ma non direi che “non ha senso domandarsi se sia una parola di uso frequente o raro”. Ha senso eccome, e i corpora linguistici, le analisi sull'uso e la disponibilità lessicali fanno proprio questo. Poi è verissimo che uno è libero di usare qualsiasi termine indipendentemente dai dati sull'uso, se lo fa consapevolmente.

Answer (score -1):

*Nonsocosa*, come unica parola, è un termine specifico dell'interazione colloquiale ed è da evitare nello scritto, a parte che non si stia riportando un discorso diretto o un pensiero (come nel caso evidenziato dall'OP).

Deriva, in modo quasi onomatopeico, dalla frettolosità con cui si risolve un'indecisione durante il colloquio:

> Quando l'ho incontrato aveva fra le mani un... *nonsocosa* che continuava ad agitare.

Qui si ha che il parlante voleva definire un oggetto ma, non sapendolo meglio descrivere, dopo l'indecisione è stato costretto a dargli un *nome posticcio*.

Se si volesse rappresentare lo stesso episodio in uno scritto sarebbe meglio una frase del tipo:

> Quando l'ho incontrato non so cosa avesse fre le mani, ma continuava ad agitarlo.